# I can't select the correct row while using CheckedTextView in ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, checkedtextview

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list, R.layout.contact_item, new String[] { "name" }, new int[] { R.id.name });
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        CheckedTextView checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        checkedTextView.toggle();
        System.out.println(checkedTextView.getText().toString());
    }
});
```

While I click the first item in the ListView, but the CheckedTextView will selected the last item in the ListView, and the System.out is correct. I don't know why, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try this link: http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/listview-with-checkboxes-without-listactivity.php

Comment: Refer this document: http://appfulcrum.com/2010/09/12/listview-example-3-simple-multiple-selection-checkboxes/    A very good example is given. I hope it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

`View`s used in the actual rows of `ListView` instances are often recycled: typically the display layer will create as many `View` objects as there are visible rows and then will cycle through them. Selection of rows where you are using an embedded `View` are often tricky: when you click on a specific View within a row the text may be correct but the system may not know which row to select. Try calling `setSelection` with the position to force the right row to be selected.

EDIT: no guarantees but try doing this and see if it works.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        CheckedTextView checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        checkedTextView.toggle();
        System.out.println(checkedTextView.getText().toString());
        getListView().setSelection(position);
    }
});
```